# How to show range of salary in Tableau bar charts

Tags: range, tableau-api

I have the following wage data in excel.

[click here to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwZ7M.png)

In Tableau, I would like to display the Wage Range and the number of pax that fall into that range.

Do I created calculated field? How do I display it using bar charts?

Tableau novice here, so your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Read about bin fields in the online help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a calculated field, like so:

```
if [Salary] >= 6000 and [Salary] < 7000
then 'between 6000 and 6999'
elseif [Salary] >= 7000 and [Salary] < 8000
then 'between 7000 and 7999'
elseif [Salary] >= 8000 and [Salary] < 9000
then 'between 8000 and 8999'
else 'out of range'
end
```

Then in the Row shelf, put `Job Title` and `Wage Range`.

Put `CNT(Number of Records)` in the Text box of the Marks card.